# Android Build class string encoding

Tags: android, utf-8

I am writing an app where I want to get the model type of the device and relay it to my server. I am currently doing this in this way:

```
try{
    String path = URLEncoder.encode(Build.MODEL, "utf-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodeingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(baseUrl + "/" + path);
```

My question is if the Build.MODEL string that is returned will always be UTF-8 encoded?

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: All strings in Java are UTF-16 encoded in memory. If you request `encode()` to encode such a string as UTF-8, the output will be UTF-8 encoded, where appropriate byte octets are formatted in `%HH` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java strings (UTF-16) can be encoded as UTF-8, see [this method in String class, it clearly mentions](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) all strings can be encoded as UTF-8.

So in your code above, `path` String is guaranteed to [always come out as UTF-8 encoded](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).